# cannot register wcf with autofac

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

I'm trying to register wcf service with autofac in hexagonal architecture where only core layer reference to UI layer and all other layers refer to DI layer.
I'm sharing what i've done so far.

Service.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="DemoApp.WebService.IAbcService, DemoApp.WebService"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"
     CodeBehind="AbcService.svc.cs" %>
```

Service.svc.cs

```
public class AbcService : IAbcService
{
    private readonly IService<Person> _service;

    public AbcService(IService<Person> service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
    public List<PersonDataContract> GetAllPerson()
    {
        var query = _service.GetAll().Distinct();

        List<PersonDataContract> studentList = new List<PersonDataContract>();

        query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
        {
            studentList.Add(new PersonDataContract
            {
                PersonID = Convert.ToString(rec.Id),
                Age = Convert.ToString(rec.Age),
                Height = rec.Height,
                Name = rec.FullName,
                Sex = rec.Sex.ToString(),
                Nationality = rec.Nationality.ToString(),
                Weight = rec.Weight.ToString()
            });
        });
        return studentList;
    }
}
```

When i try to add reference of this service layer to any other project then it gives this error:

> The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before
>   services can be instantiated.

Please guide me with this.

Comment: Please post the code from your WCF service app where dependencies are registered and the `AutofacServiceHost.Container` gets set so we might be able to repro/troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written code in the application startup to register the dependencies and hook it up with the Autofac DI container like this?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  // Register your service implementations.
  builder.RegisterType<TestService.Service1>();

  // Set the dependency resolver.
  var container = builder.Build();
  AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
}
```

More at http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/wcf.html

Comment: yes i've implemented this logic into my DI layer..i cannot even add service reference to my DI layer

Comment: I believe this is about hosting a WCF service. So, adding service references does not seem relevant.

The error mentions that `AutofacHostFactory.Container =` has not been executed. This varies based on how you are hosting the WCF service. If it is on a web server, the Application_Start event handler under Global.asax is where you need to have this.

Comment: actually i want to do simple thing, i have layered architecture in which DI layer is separate, UI is separate and vice versa. I need to build WCF service which can fetch or execute request or data from service data layer.

Comment: yes, DI containers such as Autofac are used to provide this kind of loose coupling across layers. The problem you are running into is that since you mention in the svc file that the factory needs to initialize the service, the factory also needs to be told about the container that can provide the concrete types. Just make sure you set `AutofacHostFactory.Container ` in the app start. Read the doc link I mention above for further reference, to understand how Autofac wires these up.

Comment: I have done exactly the same as u mentioned but it is giving the same error like before

Comment: WCF doesn't use Application_Start...It uses AppInitialize. That's your problem right there.. Everything else @sudheeshix said is correct.

Comment: That depends on how you are hosting WCF - on IIS or not.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Does anyone have a solution for this?